# What is the real usage of product attribute: quantity_and_stock_status?

Tags: magento2, stock

Magento2 has introduced new product attribute `quantity_and_stock_status` which hold the value of `is_in_stock` and `qty` from `$stockItem` object.

For those who are curios on the topic - 
[How the quantity_and_stock_status attribute value is populated in product object?](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/magento-2-quantity_and_stock_status-attribute-value-populated-product-object/)

Also, product object has stock-item information as extension_attributes which contain details info on stock/inventory.

Just wondering what was the sole purpose of introducing this new attribute?
For me, it's like overhead. Also seems they want an easy usage somewhere instead of using nested call for extension_attributes.

Please do share if anyone knows something about the real usage of this attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This attribute is deprecated. It was created to allow the merchant to manage a place of "quantity" field on product form through UI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KAndy. Is there any official truth about the fact that this attribute is deprecated?

Comment: officially, no.

Comment: So how the two fields in default level (qty and is in stock) will be populated in Admin UI?