# has quantity_and_stock_status been deprecated?

Tags: magento2

Has the '**quantity_and_stock_status**' been deprecated from Magento 2? Why is there no documentation for this?

Comment: REF - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139840/what-is-the-real-usage-of-product-attribute-quantity-and-stock-status

Comment: Indeed, that is where I came from. I don't have enough points to comment on the user's post.

Comment: I am too waiting for the official confirmation.